# Display of HIVE table in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read HIVE table in Spark 1.6.1. Everything is working as per the requirement, only the display of the table in Spark is wired. The HIVE table consists of 100 mn odd records.

```
import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

hive_context = HiveContext(sc)

db= hive_context.sql("SELECT * FROM HIVE_DB.HIVE_TBL").show()
```

As you can see, I have written the query to see the entire 100 mn records.But the output is still for 20 records. My questions:

1. Is that some kind of limitation with Spark 1.6.1?
2. If yes, has the limitation been excluded in the higher Spark versions?
3. If none of the above, then is there a way to change this configuration to see any no of records?

I have tried below query as well::

```
SELECT * FROM HIVE_DB.HIVE_TBL LIMIT 200
```

Still the same display.

Comment: I have seen the link that you have shared, and I think it is the kind of solution that needed. Though I still need to test it. Will post my finding here once done

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show()` - shows only 20 rows.  Therefore if you assign the outcome of `show()` to a variable `db`, it is going to have only 20.

Remove `show()` during assignment and use `db.limit(n)` to limit the rows.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala below code will work

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val sqlContext = new HiveContext(sc)
var db = sqlContext.sql("select *from database_name.table_name")
db.take(n).foreach(println)         #n, number of records


db = sqlContext.sql("select *from database_name.table_name").limit(n)
#n, number of records.
db.foreach(println);
```